# DRF displaying default image even if user uploaded an image

Tags: python, django

I wonder which method in which part of my Django backend I should use to change the representation of the user's profile picture/ the path of the user's profile picture.

Because I have an default image '/media/default_l.png' which is used in my model like so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # custom User models must have an integer 
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to=avatar_upload, blank=True, default='default_l.png', validators=[validators.FileExtensionValidator(['jpg','jpeg', 'gif', 'png',])])
...
```

This default image is used to display an image as long as the user didn't upload an profile image of his choice.

When the user uploads an image, he uploads the image to upload_to=avatar_upload like so:

```
def avatar_upload(instance, filename): #https://c14l.com/blog/django-image-upload-to-dynamic-path.html
        #return os.path.join('images/user_avatar/', 'user_{0}', '{1}').format(instance.user.id, filename)
        new_filename = '{}_{}.{}'.format('user',instance.pk, 'png')
        return "user_avatar/{}".format(new_filename)
```

So the default image is **/media/default_l.png**

and the uploaded image is **/media/user_avatar/user_3.png** (= user_pk.png)

The serializer for uploading an image is

```
# Upload User Profile Picture
class AvatarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True) 

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['avatar']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.instance.avatar:
            #delete if not default
            if "/media/default_l.png" not in self.instance.avatar.url:
                self.instance.avatar.delete()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**The uploading works fine** with the view

```
class UserUploadImage(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    #permission_classes = (IsLoggedInUser, )
    parser_class = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
    serializer_class = AvatarSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, pk, format=None):
        user = User.objects.get(id=pk)

        if not user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponse('Unauthorized', status=401)
            
        serializer = AvatarSerializer(data= request.data, instance=request.user)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but when I request the users data, the image path of the default image is returned!

- the path is wrong!

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "foo",
        "email": "foo@test.com",
        "description": null,
        "avatar": "/media/media/default_l.png",
        "token": .....
    }
```

As you can see, the api returns "/media/media/default_l.png" even if there is no "media" folder inside of media! I haven't figured out yet where the additional "media" is coming from...
**But I don't want to fix this 2x media in the path.
I want to display the uploaded user avatar from "/media/user_avatar/" folder**, if there is one (called "user_3.png" for example, where "3" is the pk of the user.).

I am displaying the user's data using this serializer:

```
# Load user profile
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tokens_for_user')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'description', 'avatar', 'token', )
    
    #https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt
    def get_tokens_for_user(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        }
```

To complete my data, here is the relevant settings.py config:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

#location where django collect all static files
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')# location where you will store your static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'myProject/static')]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'posts.User'
```

I am using

```
Django==2.2.9
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-rest-auth==0.9.5
django-sslserver==0.20
djangorestframework==3.9.1
djangorestframework-simplejwt==4.3.0
```

FYI:

What I have already tested is this approach

```
# Load user profile
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #HyperlinkSerializer for UserAvatar
    #userimage = serializers.ImageField()
    #dogimage = serializers.ImageField()
    puppy = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    friendnames = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, source='from_user')#FriendSerializer as Link
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tokens_for_user')
    avatar_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'description', 'friendnames', 'puppy', 'last_login', 'created_at','birthday', 'email_confirmed', 'is_premium', 'avatar','avatar_url', 'walkstatus', 'leine', 'token', )
    
    #https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt
    def get_tokens_for_user(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        } 


    def get_avatar_url(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.avatar.url)
```

assuming the correct place to implement my requirement is the `get_avatar_url` method.

But I receive `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'build_absolute_uri'`
and since I don't want to fix the path but instead display the actual avatar's path, I haven't fixed this..

I would be very happy if someone could help me out!

- How can I check if the current user has an image called "user_<user's pk>.png" in the "/media/user_avatar" folder and display it's **abolute path** instead of the avatar's default image path?
- Is `get_avatar_url` the correct place to put the code into?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so happy I have found the piece I was missing!

I have refactored the serializer to

```
# Load user profile
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    puppy = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)
    friendnames = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, source='from_user')#FriendSerializer as Link
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_tokens_for_user')
    avatar = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('puppies', 'friendnames', 'token', 'avatar' )
    
    def get_tokens_for_user(self, user):
        refresh = RefreshToken.for_user(user)

        return {
            'refresh': str(refresh),
            'access': str(refresh.access_token),
        } 


    def get_avatar(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.build_absolute_uri(obj.avatar.url)
```

While uploading pictures to different users with the known bug, I figured out that I was only changing my superusers' avatar, not the logged-in custom user that was supposed to be changed.
**I am using a custom User Model** and therefore need to use

```
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

when referencing the custom user -> as it is [described in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model)!

**This was the key!** Because now the correct path for the ImageField "avatar" is provided by the serializer!

```
    "avatar": "/media/user_avatar/user_2.png"
```

So I've solved it :) !